# Identify image depth and print size via Carrierwave, mini-magick and ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

The goal is to validate an image based on dynamic height and width parameters, as well as DPI.

ImageMagick has the following command Identify which has a number of options.

```
-density
```

will generate the geometry widthxheight

```
-verbose
```

will generate a helpful "Print size: " and "Resolution"... among 78 other different lines... where width and height need to be parsed out to meet minimum requirements +/- 2%

so how does one extract those into a method, without stepping on intermediate toes (mini-magick)?

Comment: Although it's a bit more overhead, you might want to look into using MiniExiftool for extracting metadata with ease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [section on meta-information](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) indicates, MiniMagick accesses the data using ImageMagick function in a single call, for example height density:

```
image["%y"]
```

ImageMagick has 47 [single-letter attribute percent escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)  that allows extraction of the data, provided your call to the image contains a ".path" suffix

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(@yourClass.theColumn.path)
```